# how to add Pagination in Woo commerce product on a custom page in flatorsome theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78lh3.jpg)

How to add pagination woo-commerce product in custom page. Any short of code available. So kindly give me a reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "wp-pagenavi" plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Comment: i need pagination like product categorey page here is any shortcode available to doing this acept wp page navi plugin